# Connecting Swift To PHP Code

Tags: php, json, swift

I am trying to encode a simple string on my website written in php:

`json_encode("str");
echo json_encode("str");`

In Swift, how would I then retrieve that string. I currently have a func that reports the HTTPBody.

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: myUrlWhereThePHPCodeWasWritten), cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?


    let jsonString = ""
    request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"



    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)


    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        println("HTTP response: \(response)")
    } else {
        println("No HTTP response")
    }
}
```

How do I get it to print out the "str" itself. I am a noob and basically trying to create a hello world version of this process.

Comment: The [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) projects would be a good place for you to start looking.

Comment: BTW, it does no harm, but there's no point in setting the `HTTPBody` of `GET` request, because with `GET` requests, all of the parameters belong in the URL itself. You only use `HTTPBody` with `POST` (or similar) requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you were going to use `sendSynchronousRequest`, you should get the `NSData` as the return value:

   ```
   if let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error) {
       // if JSON

       var parseError: NSError?
       if let responseObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? NSDictionary {
           println("string = \(responseObject)")
       } else {
           println("parseError = \(parseError)")
       }

       // if simple string
       //
       // let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       // println("string = \(string)")
   } else {
       println("error = \(error)")
   }

   if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
       println("HTTP response: \(response)")
   } else {
       println("No HTTP response")
   }
   ```
2. But I would advise against `sendSynchronousRequest`. Or, at least don't call it from the main thread. Use asynchronous method, such as:

   ```
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: nil) {
       response, data, error in

       if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
           println("HTTP response: \(response)")
       } else {
           println("No HTTP response")
       }

       if data != nil {
           // if JSON

           var parseError: NSError?
           if let responseObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? NSDictionary {
               println("string = \(responseObject)")
           } else {
               println("parseError = \(parseError)")
           }

           // if simple string
           //
           // let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
           // println("string = \(string)")
       } else {
           println("error = \(error)")
       }
   }
   ```

   Or use `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(...)` or something like that.

---

BTW, in both of those examples above, I used `as NSDictionary` when parsing the JSON. If you're generating a JSON array, then change that to `as NSArray`.

Note: I inferred from the PHP `json_encode` that you wanted to generate a valid JSON response. But you cannot just `json_encode` a string. Generally you'd `json_encode(["key" => "string"])` to generate a dictionary or `json_encode(["string"])` to generate an array.